# How to enable a field if a determined option is chosen?

Tags: php, html

I have a form in which when the user chooses certain option in a select drop-down, a new field should shows up for entering another piece of information.

Basically, it's the common "Where did you hear about us?" and when the user selects `other`, a new empty field is shown so that he can type the source if it wasn't in the list.

But I really have no clue about how to do it. I've been using PHP and HTML to do the form and validating it.

To add some code, this is where I create the select

```
<label for="where_heard">Where heard:</label>
<select name="where_heard"> <?php echo $sources; ?>
</select>
```

And this is where I get the source list from:

```
$query = "SELECT source FROM where_heard";
$stmt = $db->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute();
$sources = "";
while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
    $sources .= '<option value= "'.$row['source'].'">'.$row['source'].'</option>';
}
```

Comment: You probably need to have JS that sets display/visibilty of the container that is display:none/visibility:hidden when the page is loaded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with jquery like:

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('select').on("change",function(){
       if($(this).val() == "other")
            $(".other").html("Other: <input type='text' name='other'/>");
       else
           $(".other").html("");
    
    })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label for="where_heard">Where heard:</label>
<select name="where_heard"><option></option><option value="other">Other</option>
</select>
<div class="other"></div>
```

Comment: Where am I supposed to add the first code? I added it right after the select, but it doesn't work. Yes... total noob on web developing :)

Comment: @yzT, first, add `<script..jquery..></script>` to the `<head>`, then wrap the code with another `<script>...</script>` and add it to the `<head>` too.

Comment: @yzT you can add it inside your html `<head></head>` tag, something like `<Head><script>//the code here</script></Head>`

Comment: Ok, I was missing the <div>

Comment: @yzT ok, I'm glad you picked that up, does it work fine now?